# Multi-Valued Field Collection Token Issue

Tags: entities, tokens

I have a field collection field in a content type that takes multiple values.  I am trying to access single values of that field to use via a token.  The issue is the following:

(the field is called field_slides)

The token [node:field_slides] returns to me the html for all of the values of the field. 
The token [node:field_slides:1] etc does not work. 
The token [node:field-slides:1] does work but it resolves to the string "slides 2"
I can get at the internal values of the fields as follows: 
[node:field-slides:1:title] gives me the value of the title field within the individual entry.

I would like to simply access the html for the individual value which should be accessible through either: 
[node:field_slides:1]
or 
[node:field-slides:1] 
but it isn't.

Any ideas?

Comment: A little late, but you should be able to access it by `[node:field-slides:1:value]`